# How to make button which executes a Javascript code have its own URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have already posted this but I am going to explain it better with a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ktb9wcbm/3/). Hence, the repost.

I apologize if this has already been asked but I have been looking everywhere and I can't find any help at all.

I have made 'tabs' using anchors with `href='#'`. However, what I want is when I click button1 it changes the url to www.myurl.com/btn1 and when I click button 2 - www.myurl.com/btn2.

When I visit www.myurl.com/btn1 I want button1 to be highlighted as it is when clicked on the jsFiddle.I've searched everywhere but found no way of doing this.

Comment: You might want to explore the possibilities provided by a MVx type framework (Angular, React, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is by using the fragment of the URL to store the `id` of the tab, ie. `myurl.com#tab1`. You can then check on load if the URL has a fragment (using `location.hash`) and set the default tab and you can use the exact same mechanism in the `href` attribute of the `a` elements you use to change tabs. Try this:

```js
$('.tab-trigger').click(function() {
  showTab($(this).attr('href'));
})

if (window.location.hash)
  showTab(window.location.hash);
    
function showTab(tab) {
  $('.tab-content').hide();
  $(tab).fadeIn();
}
```

```css
.tab-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#div1" class="tab-trigger">Button 1</a>
<a href="#div2" class="tab-trigger">Button 2</a>
<a href="#div3" class="tab-trigger">Button 3</a>

<div id="div1" class="tab-content">div 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="tab-content">div 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="tab-content">div 3</div>
```